# Mysterious template change after database import/export

Tags: templates, database, post-meta

When I switch databases from my local environment to the host, some of the pages inexplicably  change templates.

E.g. there is a custom template "Home" and when I switch the db's it ends up with the template "About". I figure it's something with the post metadata not saving correctly.

It gets annoying to check every template to see whether it changed or not.

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields and WPML plugins but not sure if this issue is related.

Does anyone recognize this issue?

Comment: I've found WPML to be troublesome a few times - corrupting pages so that they have to be replaced, breaking seo urls. I'd definitely investigate whether disabling it before the transfer helps in any way.

Comment: What's your db migration process? Do you have any non-native functionality that has to do with those templates?

Comment: I export with Sequel Pro locally and import with Sequel Pro (over SSH) at the remote database server. So a very regular process. Thanks.

Comment: Do the meta_values and post_ids in wp_postmeta (those with a_wp_page_template meta_key) match up between the dev and production versions?